# Convergence of the pronouns "он" and "я"

Tags: словоупотребление

In a story, I came across the exclamation:

> И вот **он я** - живой и здоровый!

Was this a typo, or is it in actual use and what does it mean?

Comment: Note that you may stress either "_вот_" or "_я_", but not "_он_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Alex S said, **вот он я** is a fixed construction, and you're not likely to find the two pronouns in a row anywhere else. It sounds colloquial and kind of jovial — your example is very typical of its use — but curiously, the **он** seems to also be semi-mandatory. You can't just say **вот я** except in specific situations: when you're calling out to someone who can't seem to locate you ("I'm *here*!"), or you're pointing to an effigy of yourself — as in a photo ("that's me there"), or if you're explaining/reenacting something using objects ("so suppose this [pencil] is me and this [eraser] is the car, and it whizzed past me just liiiike this": *вот я, вот машина, и та-а-а-к вот она мимо меня пронеслась*). **Вот он я**, on the other hand, is always about your literal physical self in the here-and-now, and the message it conveys is that you're present at all, not where exactly you are.

[Disregard the part in my original answer about emphasis on *вот* vs. emphasis on *я*. Didn't think of enough examples. It's not really a factor.]

Comment: Excellent answer as usual. You mentioned that the element он is quasi-mandatory in this usage, since you can't just say вот я (except in the cases you pointed out). However, would вот и я have the same force?

Comment: @CocoPop Great observation, I forgot about **вот и я** too. It's more stylistically neutral — while having a stronger connotation of arrival/turning up whereas **вот он я** can also be used if the speaker had been there all along. The two do overlap a great deal nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

*Он* in *вот он* is a clitic (a word which does not have an accent on its own). Phonetically, *вот он* is a single word.

Since Russian normally omits copula in a sentence, *вот он* is perceived as a deictic adverb on its own, with a meaning slightly different from a mere *вот*, as noted in the answers above.

There are other phrases in vernacular Russian similar in origin: *вот так вот, вот это вот, как же ж так* etc, produced by adding a particle or an adverb to a (seemingly) one word which already had it.

Zaliznyak mentions there was a period in old Russian when the reflexive pronoun *ся*, which was on its way from an unbound morpheme to the postfix it is now, was used *twice* with the reflexive verbs: *мнѣ сѧ не можетсѧ, а то сь диѧлось*.

Comment: Thank you for that, Quassnoi. ¿Is this expression only used as an independent exclamation, or can it form part of a bigger thought such as: ну, ты должно быть собираешься начать день и вот он я так рано мешаю.

Comment: @CocoPop Both OK.

Answer (score 2):

"Вот он я" is a fixed grammatical construction which means "look, here I am".
A female person would say "вот она я" and a group of people — "Вот они мы".

See also answers to this question: [What's the difference between “вот” and “здесь”?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11494/whats-the-difference-between-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-and-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Alex. ¿Does this clitic only work with я, or would it be possible to say: Я только что думал о тебе и вот он ты.

Comment: @CocoPop In this context "вот он ты" sounds natural.